# Nest Js Typeorm Query

Tags: sql, repository, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to run a query at the repository level of my nestjs application.

The date format of the column (runDateTime) in my DB is isoString. I want to find all the records that have **runDateTime** of today's date.

I have a function called *Parsebackenddate* that essentially converts iso string to YYYY-MM-DD. how do i use this function with "schedule.runDateTime" in order to compare both dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD?

Or is there an alternative?

```
if (getToday) {
      const todayDate = dayjs().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      query.where('schedule.runDateTime = :todayDate', {
        todayDate,
      });
``

Much appreciated.
```

Answer (score 0):

first, you have to get a date from the database and hold it in a class variable then compare.
something like that may this could help.

```
var _orderBean = new date_beans();    
 _orderBean.dueDate = _response[a].dueDate.toISOString().slice(0,10); //YYYY-MM-DD
```

then compare

```
var d = new Date(); //todaydate
if(d.toISOString().slice(0,10)>_orderBean.dueDate)
// TodayDate > DueDate
```